# Maneira para executar um tipo de query em Django

Tags: python, django

Estou com dificuldades para executar um tipo específico de Query no Django.
Estou querendo trazer as aulas que estão vinculadas a um mesmo modulo, por exemplo:
aula 1, 2, 3 e 4 estão vinculadas ao modulo 1, mas quero trazer destas aulas as que pertencem ao mesmo professor (aula 1 e 2 são do professor 1). E gostaria que a query trouxesse apenas Aula 1 e 2, neste caso.
Como se fosse:

```
SELECT * 
FROM departamento_aulavinculamodulo DeAuMo
INNER JOIN departamento_aula DeAu
ON DeAu.id = DeAuMo.aula_id
WHERE DeAu.professor_id = 1;
```

Abaixo estão os models das tabelas em python/django

```
class Modulo(models.Model):
    modulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cod_modulo = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    lingua = models.ForeignKey(Lingua, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    nivel = models.ForeignKey(NivelLingua, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Aula(models.Model):
    aula = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    conteudo = models.TextField()
    conteudo_download = models.FileField(
        upload_to='conteudo_aula/%Y/%m', blank=True, null=True
    )
    data_post = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    nivel = models.ForeignKey(NivelLingua, default=1,
                              on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    modulo = models.ManyToManyField(
        Modulo, blank=True, through='AulaVinculaModulo')
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    aula_gravada = models.FileField(upload_to='aula/%Y/%m')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.aula
```

```
class AulaVinculaModulo(models.Model):
    aula = models.ForeignKey(
        Aula, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modulos')
    modulo = models.ForeignKey(
        Modulo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='aulas')
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das formas que eu mais gosto de resolver esses problemas como **Query** no Django é trabalhando direto na **View** da model, lá eu consigo ter mais liberdade para resolver esse tipo de problema. Mas isso não quer dizer que esse seja o único método também o mais eficaz para o que você deseja fazer. Mas vamos lá resolver esse problema.

A primeira coisa que você tem que fazer é deixar todas as **ForeignKey** bem organizadas para não se perder quando chegar no arquivo View de seu projeto.

Para resolução desse problema eu criei 3 models: Modulos, Aulas e Professor. A model **Modulos**, é a principal e vai ser complementada pela model de **Aulas**, já essa segunda será dependente da model de **Professor**.

> Models

```
from django.db import models


class Modulo(models.Model):
    modulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cod_modulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ligua = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Modulo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Modulos'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.modulo}'


class Professor(models.Model):
    professor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    idade = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Professor'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Professores'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.professor}'


class Aula(models.Model):
    modulo = models.ForeignKey(Modulo, related_name="Aulas", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    professor = models.ForeignKey(Professor, related_name="Professor", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    aula = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    conteudo = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Aula'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Aulas'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.aula}'
```

Em um breve resumo do código acima, a model de Professor está sendo incluída dentro da model da aulas, dessa fora você pode vincular um professor a determinada aula. Já as aulas estão sendo incluídas dentro de determinado modulo, dessa mesma forma você consegue incluir a aula dentro de um modulo.

> Serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Modulo, Aula, Professor


class Serializers_Professor(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Professor
        fields = (
            'id',
            'professor',
            'idade'
        )


class Serializers_Aula(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Aula
        fields = (
            'id',
            'modulo',
            'aula',
            'conteudo',
            'professor'
        )


class Serializers_Modulo(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Aulas = Serializers_Aula(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Modulo
        fields = (
            'id',
            'modulo',
            'cod_modulo',
            'ligua',
            'Aulas'
        )
```

No serializer coloquei um nested **Aulas** dentro do `Serializers_Modulo`, dessa forma vamos conseguir visualizar quais são as aulas que estão vinculadas a determinado modulo.

> View

```
from .models import Aula, Modulo, Professor
from .serializers import Serializers_Aula, Serializers_Modulo, Serializers_Professor

from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response


class View_Modulo(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Modulo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Serializers_Modulo

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'], url_path='professor/(?P<professor_pk>[^/.]+)')
    def professor(self, request, professor_pk, pk=None,):
        obj_Aulas = Aula.objects.filter(professor_id=professor_pk)
        serializer = Serializers_Aula(obj_Aulas, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)


class View_Aula(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Aula.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Serializers_Aula


class View_Professor(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Professor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Serializers_Professor
```

Agora para a resolução do problema: Dentro da View da model Modulo, inserimos uma action (rota) do tipo get, e vamos personalizar ela para fazer uma Query personalizada para seu projeto.

A primeira coisa que vamos fazer é deixar o `detail=True`, dessa forma vamos conseguir acessar apenas 1 modulo em especifico, e na  mesma action vamos colocar o código `url_path='professor/(?P<professor_pk>[^/.]+)'`. O que fizemos nessa pequena parte de código já é praticamente toda a Query que você deseja fazer. Em resumo: estamos dizendo que a rota vai ser lida assim: 'modulos/1/professor/2/'. Já consegue ver a restApi se formando?

Após isso, dentro da função professor vamos adicionar um parâmetro chamado 'professor_pk', e vamos adicionar uma variável chamada 'modulo', e dentro dela vamos armazenar o modulo que iremos buscar, imagine que fizemos a parte 'modulos/1'. Agora na variável obj será a parte principal de nossa `Query`, vamos instanciar o model `Aulas` e vamos fazer dois filtros: o primeiro filtro é para que seja listado apenas determinado modulo e vamos passar nossa primeira variável, dessa forma `filter(modulo=modulo)`, o segundo filtro será para filtrar o professor de determinado modulo, e vamos passar nosso parâmetro 'professor_pk', dessa forma `filter(professor_id=professor_pk)`. Depois de tudo isso, basta serializar o obj com o `Serializers_Aula` e retornar para o usuário o que ele deseja ver. Lembre-se colocar o `many=True`, para que seja listada mais de 1 aula.

Caso você tenha ficado com alguma dúvida ou queira saber mais sobre as funções dentro da View, basta acessar a documentação do próprio Django: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions